# Installing QGIS on computer which has ArcGIS Desktop?

Tags: qgis, arcgis-desktop, python, installation

I have ArcGIS Desktop on my computer, but I want to install QGIS 3.8 as well. The installation finishes successfully as it says, but I can't find many files after and the program is not working.
I think, the problem is ArcGIS Desktop 10 which I have on the same comuter. I tried to install QGIS 3.2 too, with the same bad result.

My solution was that I had a clean QGIS install on another computer and copied those files to this installation folder, and the program is now working.

Is there any interference between these (ArcGIS Desktop & QGIS) programs?

Even with Python or something else?

Comment: But you get an error? Arcgis and Qgis can be on the same machine without problems

Comment: The installer says that it was sucessfully, but after the installation, I can't find the created QGIS folder on my desktop (4 files should be there), no shortcut file either, and when I want to start the program with qgis-bin.exe in the bin folder, it says that can't find a dll file. But the this dll file is in the right place.

Comment: you can try to install OSGeo4W and run qgis using qgis.bat

Comment: "10" isn't an ArcGIS release, it's a family of releases dating back to 2010.  I'd expect that a *modern* ArcGIS release would be compatible, but not something ancient.

Comment: Now I can use the program with the solution I mentioned, but I will have to install it on other computers. I will see that then.
I will report the results. Thanks for the answers!

Comment: i have numerous versions of Qgis and ArcMap 10.6 on my Windows 7 computer and have not had any issues.

Comment: I also have Arcgis 10.3.1, QGIS 3.4.2 and QGIS 3.8.0 on a Windows 7 and I have no problem using all three at the same time.

Comment: There should be no issues between arcgis/qgis including python they are separate installs, though windows can be the issue not the applications.

Comment: During installation, make sure that your installation file is not blocked by the antivirus software. When popup menu shows, you have to allow some files to install.